# Mounting multiple img files as single loop device

Tags: linux, block-device, loop-device

Is there a way to take a disk img file that is broken up into parts and mount it as a single loop device?

Comment: How is it broken? What format is it? There might be some fuse magic for this if it's a special format, but I suspect the answer is to cat them together!

Comment: I am restricted by the format of the device to files that are less the 4 gigs. I have root access though to the device. Is there something I can with LVM

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in place but if you have enough space this should work:

```
# Create the files that will hold your data
dd if=/dev/zero of=part-00 bs=1M count=4k
dd if=/dev/zero of=part-01 bs=1M count=4k

# Create the loop devices
losetup /dev/loop0 part-00
losetup /dev/loop1 part-01

# Create a RAID array
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1

# Copy the original filesystem
dd if=original-file-00 of=/dev/md0 bs=512
# Look at the records written value
dd if=original-file-01 of=/dev/md0 bs=512 seek=<sum of records written values so far>

# Mount the new filesystem
mount /dev/md0 /mnt
```

You can't simply create a RAID array from the original files because the RAID disks have a specific header where the number of disks, RAID level, etc is stored. If you do it that part of your original files will be overwritten.

You can use the `mdadm --build` to create an array without metadata but then you really should make a backup first. Or if read-only mount is enough:

```
losetup -r /dev/loop0 original-00
losetup -r /dev/loop1 original-11
mdadm --build /dev/md0 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
mount /dev/md0 /mnt
```

Why do you want to do this? If your filesystem can't handle >4GB files you should just switch to a sane one.

Comment: Might be able to do it with device mapper too, but the above is easier.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept, very good answer.I would not do this under normal circumstance, its more of an adventure mode question.

Comment: You probably want to use `truncate` instead of `dd` as it is much faster (it does not perform actual write to FS but just allocates inodes and mark file as just containing hole).

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that.

Comment: From experience, if you use large capacity cloud-based backup or syncing solutions like CrashPlan or paid Google Drive it is a *very, very* good idea to use small split files instead of a single huge file. In the event of a failed file download, you will only have to re-download, say, 1 GB instead of the whole 100 GB thing.

Comment: Also, I just tried this method. It works perfectly fine with 25 loop drives. Just for the record: after initializing your linear RAID array for the first time, you should start your previously created array with either `mdadm --assemble --scan` or (I would use this second one if I already had mdadm RAID arrays in my system) `mdadm --assemble /dev/<the md device you created before> <your loop devices separated by spaces>`.

Comment: And now I tested it with 50 loop drives. No problems so far.

Answer (score 4):

To mount a split disk image (or partition image) you should use `affuse` from the afftools which are currently maintained here: https://github.com/sshock/AFFLIBv3

So, if you have a file, split up into several subfiles `test_img.000, test_img.001, test_img.002, test_img.003, test_img.004, test_img.005, test_img.006, test_img.007, test_img.008, test_img.009`

then you can join them virtually with `affuse`

```
# affuse test_img.000 /mnt/combine
# ls -lh /mnt/combine
total 0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2.0G 1969-12-31 16:00 test_img.000.raw
```

(this combines all files together starting with file 000, then 001, 002, …)

And then mount the image

```
mount -o ro,loop,offset=329043456 /mnt/combine/test_img.000.raw /mnt/test
```

The usage is described [here](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Affuse) and some examples [here](https://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2010/09/15/dealing-split-raw-type-images). A manpage is also available after compiling and installing, or [here](http://manpages.org/affuse).

PS: For me `affuse` only worked if the split files had a size which was a multiple of 512 bytes.

Comment: I just tried this method. It has a major caveat: it will only allow you to mount your image as read only.

Comment: Works great as long as you only have hundreds and not thousands of file chunks.  Might be better off using mdadm to create a linear raid partition: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98779/22709

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own block storage device extension (think of fuse-like extension) and perform seeks dependently on what's the address.

Here you can find example of how to use fuse 
https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse/blob/master/example/hello.py

Comment: thank you I really should wrap my head around the meta circularness of that one day

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I know so far to a solution is to create a VMware VM. You start a Linux live CD like Rescatux or Knoppix, you create a SMB shared folder on your host computer, you mount that SMB share on your VM, and then you `dd` the image into the virtual HD. VMware by default saves its disk images as split files, so this is the closest thing to reading directly a disk image split into multiple files.

Later, if you want to access the files from your host computer, you can try adding a second virtual HD to the image and copying the files there. Then you set up a SMB shared folder on the VM and connect to it from your host. This way you can, for example, violate the 4 GB file limit of FAT32 in the event that you're using an iPod Classic (which only groks fat32), or your smartphone's SD card (usually you have to install a custom ROM in order to use Ext3 or NTFS on the external storage, for this you require a phone from a popular manufacturer like Samsung or Motorola, so if you have a Chinese smartphone you're stumped).

It is admittedly not an efficient solution, however, but since I've been limited by not being able to use any FS other than fat32 on my iPod Classic or my Samsung smartphones with stock ROM, I have scoured pretty much the entire internet in the past and still am not able to find an efficient solution to this. I might even have to write it myself.

PS: Forgot to mention, that if you're on Windows this might be the only way to do this.

Comment: It's been some time since I visited this problem. I still have it. Also I have it exactly the same reason you do. I wonder if you can bring up a process that has it's own custom file system, honestly I would love to attempt this. I know I can do it in node. I've had success bringing the interpreter up in rooted. I don't know if this solves your problem though if I did. On my hardware samsung galaxies this is fine. Tell me would you like to work on something for this problem together.

Answer (score -1):

Under BSD you can use the union option to mount.
Under Linux you can give a try to unionFS.

Comment: This doesn't look remotely relevant. Did you misread the question?