# How to add more /dev/loop* devices on Fedora 19

Tags: linux, fedora, kernel, loop-device

How to add more /dev/loop* devices on Fedora 19? I do:

```
# uname -r
3.11.2-201.fc19.x86_64
# lsmod |grep loop

# ls /dev/loop*
/dev/loop0  /dev/loop1  /dev/loop2  /dev/loop3  /dev/loop4  /dev/loop5  /dev/loop6  /dev/loop7  /dev/loop-control
# modprobe loop max_loop=128
# ls /dev/loop*
/dev/loop0  /dev/loop1  /dev/loop2  /dev/loop3  /dev/loop4  /dev/loop5  /dev/loop6  /dev/loop7  /dev/loop-control
```

So nothing changes.

Comment: loop isn't a module in fedora 19, its compiled in.

Comment: you'd probably use `mknod`. but why would you want to create more loop files without connecting them to anything?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to create device nodes into `/dev` with mknod. The device nodes in `dev` have a type (block, character and so on), a major number and a minor number. You can find out the type and the major number by doing `ls -l /dev/loop0`:

```
user@foo:/sys# ls -l /dev/loop0
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 7, 0 Oct  8 08:12 /dev/loop0
```

This means loop device nodes should have the block type and major number of 7. The minor numbers increment by one for each device node, starting from 0, so loop0 is simply 0 and loop7 is 7.

To create loop8 you run, as root, command `mknod -m 0660 /dev/loop8 b 7 8`. This will create the device node `/dev/loop8` with permissions specified along the `-m` switch (that's not necessary as you're probably running a desktop system, but it's a good idea not to let everyone read and write your device nodes).

Comment: You forgot the node type after the name, so the command should be `mknod -m 0660 /dev/loop8 b 7 8`.

Answer (score 21):

When you run it as root, `losetup -f` will automatically create loop devices as needed if there aren't any free ones available.

So rather than doing it yourself with `mknod`, the easiest way to create a new loop device is with `sudo losetup -f`. That approach will give you a free existing loop device if one exists, or automatically create a new one if needed.

Comment: The error message you get when running `losetup -f` as a non-root user currently isn't very helpful though, so I filed https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1215370 to suggest improving that.

Comment: Based on that report, the losetup error changed to be `Permission denied` rather than `No such file or directory`, giving a better nudge to trying again with more privileges.

Answer (score 7):

Heh, incomplete :) Simply use this script for adding new /dev/loops. Remember for changing numbers, script makes to 63'th loop, starts from 8'th because 0-7 is made by default. Notice, rights are copied from /dev/loop0 :)

```
for i in {8..63}; do if [ -e /dev/loop$i ]; then continue; fi; \
mknod /dev/loop$i b 7 $i; chown --reference=/dev/loop0 /dev/loop$i; \
chmod --reference=/dev/loop0 /dev/loop$i; done
```

Notice, recipe above are from 2014 year. At now is 2023 year :) Currently developed kernel creates all /dev/ device by devfs virtual filesystem. For backward compatibility it displays 0 to 7 loop device automatically, but it creates additional loop devices when it is needed. At now there is no limit 256 loop devices encoded by 1 byte minor number. Modern kernels supports 2 byte minor number, then limit is 65535 devices.

This is currently used in union like filesystems, for Docker or K8S containers.

Finally, recipe for modern systems is useless