# how to add a loop device on fedora 23 with losetup?

Tags: linux, fedora, mount, encryption, loop-device

in an attempt to access a truecrypt container, I stumbled about the prerequisite of setting up a loop device...

ncoghlan suggested in an earlier [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98742/how-to-add-more-dev-loop-devices-on-fedora-19)

> When you run it as root, losetup -f will automatically create loop devices as needed if there aren't any free ones available.
>   So rather than doing it yourself with mknod, the easiest way to create a new loop device is with sudo losetup -f. That approach will give you a free existing loop device if one exists, or automatically create a new one if needed.

My result of "sudo losetup –f" is

```
losetup: –f: failed to use device: No such file or directory
```

Searching for this message+losetup so far does not help.

Result of "lsmod |grep loop" is

```
loop                   28672  0
```

uname -r

```
4.5.7-200.fc23.x86_64
```

Comment: `sudo losetup -f` requires an argument - a file to be set up as a backing storage for the loop device (the file containing your virtual disk/fs image)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serge's comment made me do my homework - study the man page in more depth than before. The solution was simply to enter in the shell

```
losetup
```

(without any arguments). Then, afterwards,

```
losetup -f
```

resulted, successfully, in

```
/dev/loop0
```