# Combine mkfifo and cp --reflink to append files without copying data

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, fifo, reflink

I have huge files `{0..9}.bin` which I want concatenate into `out.bin`. I don't need the original files afterwards. So I was wondering, if this is possible by only modifying the filesystem index without copying the file contents (see [Append huge files to each other without copying them](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80429/234981) for efficient copy solutions).

On modern file systems (e.g. btrfs) `cp --reflink=always` exists. Fifos are on the file system level (at least `btrfs send` also tracks fifos), so they should have information about the actual data blocks used. Therefore, `cp --reflink=always` should be able to determine the extend numbers on disk and re-use them.

So I was wondering, if it is possible to use `mkfifo` in combination with `cp --reflink=always`?

**Update**
Currently, it is not working:

```
for i in {1..9}; do dd if=/dev/urandom of="in$i.bin" bs=5M count=200; done;
mkfifo fifo
cat in* >fifo &
cp --reflink=always fifo out.bin
```

results in
`cp: failed to clone 'out.bin' from 'fifo': Invalid argument`

Probably, it never will, since FIFOs have no information about the storage origin bug instead are just dumb pipes.

Comment: Is your intention to save space or to save on write operations?

Comment: @Kusalanada: Save on write operations (speed).

Comment: Why do you think a fifo helps you achieve your goal? A fifo (named pipe) is a tool that enables pushing data into and out of a RAM buffer abstracted by a special file. It is not a file and does not map blocks.... Maybe you're on to something, I just can't work it out.

Comment: @Pedro: Yes, I am new to fifos, but inspecting this code https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80439/234981 leads me to the conclusion that `cat *.bin > myfifo.bin` does not actually copy the contents into RAM but instead reference them somehow.

Comment: I believe that would lock until you read off the fifo, so the data goes nowhere until you cat myfifo.bin somewhere. `cp --reflink=always` refers to copy-on-write block operations - meaning blocks are not duplicated until they're written to, although this refers to files stored on the file system, not a fifo (which isn't actually a file with data blocks).

Comment: I suggest you try `cat *.bin > out.bin` and check whether it's acceptable performance and space consumption. If it is, you're solving a problem that isn't a problem. I completely understand the logic of your question and conceptually the concatenation will duplicate all data blocks unnecessarily, but I don't think there's a mechanism that avoids this. Have a look at this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118244/fastest-way-to-concatenate-files

Comment: @Pedro: I read this thread and actually have been inspired for my question after reading it! The use-case is the high-performance cloud storage provider [minio](https://github.com/minio/minio). Currently (in fs mode), chunks are saved when they arrive for S3 compliance. After the last chunk has been received, all files are concatenated and and copied to the appropriate location. It is used by TBs of data every day!

Comment: It may not be worth the effort and/or beyond your capabilities but an elegant solution would be to use FUSE for this. You would have to write a FUSE FS which shows just one file (the combined one, as immutable at best) and maps the reading position into the respective source file. I didn't check. Maybe someone has already done that. ;-)

Comment: This would be a cool feature, but what should happen if each individual file doesn't fully fill its last block?

Comment: @HaukeLaging: Easier than FUSE is [losetup/dmsetup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80439/234981). But doing this for thousands of files is not a good idea - especially since read speed is crucial.

Comment: Yup, I understand your situation. Depending on your purpose for the large file, losetup *might* enable you to map a contiguous space consisting of those files? It's a guess.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17084/mounting-multiple-img-files-as-single-loop-device

Comment: @Pedro: This is similar to what I linked in my comment. As stated, this is not possible for the use-case I am describing. Thanks for your suggestions anyways!